# How do I get event emitter based code to wait in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, dom-events

I may be asking the question wrong because I don't have a lot of experience with this. Basically, I have this code:

```
videoshow(images, videoOptions)
  .audio('song.mp3')
  .save('video.mp4')
  .on('start', function (command) {
    console.log('ffmpeg process started:', command)
  })
  .on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.error('Error:', err)
    console.error('ffmpeg stderr:', stderr)
  })
  .on('end', function (output) {
    console.error('Video created in:', output)
  })
```

from [this library](https://github.com/h2non/videoshow)

It runs async as far as I understand, but I can't get it to wait even when I add await before it.

I want the block of code to stop until the `end` has finished and the image has been converted to a vide. I don't see any examples, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap it in a promise:

```
async function run() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    videoshow(images, videoOptions)
      .audio('song.mp3')
      .save('video.mp4')
      .on('start', function (command) {
        console.log('ffmpeg process started:', command)
      })
      .on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.error('Error:', err)
        console.error('ffmpeg stderr:', stderr)
        reject(err);
      })
      .on('end', function (output) {
        console.error('Video created in:', output)
        resolve(output);
      })
  )
}


(async () => {
  await run();
  // This is were you put your code
})();
```